# How to get description in openweathermap object

Tags: php, openweathermap

I get the following object from OpenWeatherMap. Now I get wind speed and direction.

```
$weather->wind->speed
$weather->wind->direction
```

And it returns

0.71 m/s 62.5018 ENE

But I want to get wind direction description East-northeast. I tried the followings but none of them worked. How can I get wind direction description.

```
$weather->wind->direction->descption
$weather->wind->direction['desctiption']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In both of your attempts, know that 'description' is misspelled which is why it did not work.

You can either correct the spelling and try again, but you should be able to do:

```
$weather->wind->direction.description
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this example](https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api/blob/master/Examples/CurrentWeather.php#L165), I just need to use `getDescription()`.

```
$weather->wind->direction->getDescription();
```